How to use MPI in Dalton software?
I'm trying to run a Dalton calculation using more than one processor. I installed OpenMPI and then built Dalton, but when I tried running the Dalton command, I got an error."
mpirun: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_pmix_ext3x.so: undefined symbol: pmix_value_load

SERIOUS ERROR:
mpirun -np 4 /home/yeddou/dalton/build/dalton.x finished with non-zero exit code: 127

here is my path:
export PATH="$PATH:/home/yeddou/openmpi/bin"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/yeddou/openmpi/lib
export PATH=/home/yeddou/dalton/build:${PATH}
export DALTON_LAUNCHER="mpirun -np 4"
export DALTON_TMPDIR="/home/yeddou/dalton/scratch"

